# Do I need to replace my chain ring and cassette? Images attached

Tags: cassette, chainring, wear

I know I should replace them if they "look like shark teeth", but I don't know what exactly what shark teeth look like. I know they don't exactly look new, but do they need to be replaced with my chain?

[image: 1st image of cassette]

[image: 2nd image of cassette]

[image: 1st image of crank]

[image: 2nd image of crank]

Comment: Doesn't look terrible to me. Do you have any chain skipping issues? I would not exchange anything if not. Some of the teeth have rams that may look as shark teeth, but you can see that they are aligned.

Comment: Vlad - thanks for your help. I have not had any skipping issues, just wanted to be safe (and reduce shipping costs if I needed to replace anything other than my chain)

Comment: I see, I do not think there will be any issues with the new chain, but wait for the more experienced. The classical shark teeth look very different. But that is the final extreme stage of wear. You are surely not there yet. I cannot speak about any intermediate wear.

Comment: The cassette looks fairly worn, but I've seen much worse.  The chainring looks fine.

Comment: Politely, that transmission could do with a clean.  This will help the parts last longer, because oils hold grit which grinds away metal faster than the wear of riding the bike.

Comment: Criggie - Thanks for the advice. I agree. Did a big clean right after I took the pics.

Comment: @Criggie: Looks very clean to me. Or has OP cleaned in the meantime and updated the pictures?

Comment: @Michael the pictures show the bike before cleaning.  There's dust on the chainrings, and oils on the cassette, which would be a lot chromier (?) when cleaned.   I'd hate to see what you call a dirty bike :)

Comment: My bike looks like that after one or two rides in fair weather, not to mention foul weather …

Comment: How many km/miles are there on that drive-train? First new chain? Rule of the thumb says: 2 chains - 1 cassette, 3 chains - front-rings. But if you replace the chains early you may add 2 chains for one new cassette and for a pair of new rings. These still look OK.

Comment: @Michael Post clean picks (de-greased then re-greesed)  https://imgur.com/a/vcLXflD It almost looks worse. Maybe I'm putting on too much chain lube? They were totally chrome after I de-greased.

Comment: @Carel - no idea. I'm going to start tracking better when I change my chain.

Comment: @MattH: One of the best tools in relation with drive trains is a chain gauge. They're quite inexpensive and tell you at one glance when the chain needs replacing. Saves a lot of money resulting from collateral damage.

Comment: @Carel Ordered one yesterday :-). That's what prompted the question: Did I need to add cassette + chain ring to my order.

Comment: @MattH: It's always a good idea to have at least one chain and one or two different cassettes on stock at home. Chain-rings are changed less frequently so that these can wait for the order to arrive.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that chain force causes wear on the edge of the upcurve of the U-shaped gap between each gear tooth, eventually eroding the tooth profile so much that it becomes V or shark-tooth shaped in extreme cases (instead of flat-topped).  The gear gap where the chain roller sits is then much wider than the roller itself, and the gear tooth is much narrower than the gap between rollers, so the chain can have slop and even slip on the gear, causing problems.
Steel gears will normally wear more slowly than alloy gears, and chainrings (front) will normally wear more slowly than rear gears of the same material.  The chain roller connections will also wear (this is called "stretch" but is just wear making the chain looser). Normally, chains get replaced more often than rear gear cassettes, which in turn get replaced more often than chainrings, but it will all vary with the materials and riding style involved.

Comment: That is true and repeated here very often, but is the cassette and the chainrings in the pictures worn?

Comment: In my *opinion* not much wear. I believe the leading upcurve in each rear gear gap is where the chain force is applied, while it is the trailing upcurve in each chainring gear gap that gets the chain force.  Those upcurves look in good shape to me.

Comment: Thanks Armand. I will continue to use.

Answer (score 3):

I bought a Dura-Ace chain ring thinking mine was worn. I was very surprised to find that the new one looked a lot like the used one. If you want to be sure ask a dealer to allow you to photograph a new large ring so you can compare them. Many modern gears are not cut in perfect arcs. This is to improve shifting performance not to increase durability. As far as the cassette is concerned it is difficult to say for sure as the picture is not face on.  My opinion based on the images is that some wear shows but not enough to necessitate replacement now.